RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2488) must match the size of tensor b (1876) at non-singleton dimension 1
This is the link to my colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IZWQsSNtmUMggVcRgg1hczN3FcIys1Rv?usp=sharing
I am working on fine-tuning my SpeechT5 model for converting the text(technical jargon asked in a technical interview) to speech.
sampling rate is set to16KHz.
I am receiving the error:- RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2488) must match the size of tensor b (1876) at non-singleton dimension 1
How to make the tensor equal?
I am not able to figure out which part of the code is causing this error
If i do so will there any matrix mismatch error because I got this error previously.
Would anyone be able to help me to fix my error? I need to submit this assignment by 23 Oct 2024
I have given the link to my colab notebook so that you can see the whole thing.
tried a lot of thing but nothing worked please help
